# Vars within function are not reset per call (LUA)

Tags: function, lua

I am trying to set a function to add min to current time object and return a new time object. I created a function for this but for some reason the vars in the functions are not been re-set / local each time I call the function.
each call to the function will use the past value of the local vars within the function, why ?

```
  local function AddTime (MinAfter, BaseTime) 


        if (MinAfter == nil) then  MinAfter = 0 end
        if (BaseTime == nil) or (BaseTime.min == nil) or (BaseTime.hour == nil)  then  BaseTime = os.date("*t") end

          BaseTime.hour = BaseTime.hour + math.floor((BaseTime.min + MinAfter)/60)
          BaseTime.min =  BaseTime.min + MinAfter - (60 * (math.floor((BaseTime.min + MinAfter)/60)))

          if BaseTime.hour > 24 then  BaseTime.hour = 24 end

          return  BaseTime

        end


        local sunriseHour = os.date("*t" ,os.time {year = 2014, month = 4, day = 19, yday = 259, wday = 4, hour = 6, min = 0, sec = 0, isdst = false});

    -- this is the original time object in this case sunraiseHour

          print ("sunriseHour time:" .. (string.format("%02d",sunriseHour.hour) .. ":" .. string.format("%02d", sunriseHour.min)));


    -- first call 

    local newtime1= AddTime(10, sunriseHour);


          print ("call 1 time:" .. string.format("%02d", newtime1.hour) .. ":" .. string.format("%02d", newtime1.min));

         -- on the 1st call  I get 07:10 which is right 

    -- 2nd call 

    local newtime2= AddTime(10, sunriseHour);


          print ("call 1 time:" .. string.format("%02d", newtime2.hour) .. ":" .. string.format("%02d", newtime2.min));


          -- on the 2nd call  I get 07:20 and not 07:10 since this was the 2nd call to the function - the BaseTime var within the function was not local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `sunriseHour` into AddTime, it is passed *by reference* rather than by value, which means that any changes made to `BaseTime` inside of AddTime are changes to `sunriseHour` -- both varibles (`sunriseHour` and `BaseTime`) point to the same object.

So when you write the following in AddTime:

```
BaseTime.hour = BaseTime.hour + math.floor((BaseTime.min + MinAfter)/60)
BaseTime.min =  BaseTime.min + MinAfter - (60 * (math.floor((BaseTime.min + MinAfter)/60)))
```

You're modifying `sunriseHour`.

It seems you don't quite understand this, because you *also* assign a new value to BaseTime inside of AddTime, which suggests you think you have a new object. If you want to create an altered *copy* of `sunriseHour`, then you'll need to either do that inside of AddTime, or create some kind of copy constructor for your time object.

Comment: You call AddTime *twice* on the same object, first adding 10, then adding another 10, which results in adding 20.

Comment: ok got you, but I do need to keep the original object unchanged as I want to call the AddTime function with few objects I need to keep as is. how do i  create a copy constructor

Comment: Create a function that copies the object. That's it. It's about as straightforward as you would think. I'll edit my post to show an example, but I don't know all the fields you object can contain.

Answer (score -1):

thanks Mud, 
I understood that I needed to copy my time object otherwise since I use a reference of it, it will modify the original object.
I found a copy function and use it to copy the object into a local one within the function

thanks

```
function table.copy(orig)
    local orig_type = type(orig)
    local copy
    if orig_type == 'table' then
        copy = {}
        for orig_key, orig_value in pairs(orig) do
            copy[orig_key] = orig_value
        end
    else -- number, string, boolean, etc
        copy = orig
    end
    return copy
end

 function AddTime (MinAdd, TimeObj) 

local BaseTime = {};
local MinAfter = 0;

if (TimeObj == nil) or (TimeObj.min == nil) or (TimeObj.hour == nil) then  BaseTime =  table.copy(os.date("*t")) else  BaseTime = table.copy(TimeObj)  end;
if (MinAdd == nil) then  MinAfter = 0 else MinAfter = MinAdd end;

    BaseTime.hour = BaseTime.hour + math.floor((BaseTime.min + MinAfter)/60)
    BaseTime.min =  BaseTime.min + MinAfter - (60 * (math.floor((BaseTime.min + MinAfter)/60)))

  if BaseTime.hour > 24 then  BaseTime.hour = 24 end

  return  BaseTime

end






        -- this is the original time object in this case sunraiseHour
         local sunriseHour = os.date("*t" ,os.time {year = 2014, month = 4, day = 19, yday = 259, wday = 4, hour = 6, min = 0, sec = 0, isdst = false});

              print ("sunriseHour time:" .. (string.format("%02d",sunriseHour.hour) .. ":" .. string.format("%02d", sunriseHour.min)));


        -- first call 

        local newtime1= AddTime(10,sunriseHour);


              print ("call 1 time:" .. string.format("%02d", newtime1.hour) .. ":" .. string.format("%02d", newtime1.min));

             -- on the 1st call  I get 07:10 which is right 

        -- 2nd call 

        local newtime2= AddTime(10,sunriseHour);


              print ("call 2 time:" .. string.format("%02d", newtime2.hour) .. ":" .. string.format("%02d", newtime2.min));


              -- on the 2nd call  I get 07:20 and not 07:10 since this was the 2nd call to the function - the BaseTime var within the function become global  




                        print ("Added time:" .. string.format("%02d", AddTime(20, sunriseHour).hour) .. ":" .. string.format("%02d", AddTime(20, sunriseHour).min));
```